# need help in import osmdroid (AndroidManifest.xml Error message)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I try to insert OpenStreetMap in my AndroidApp. I got an error, I hoe you can help me. I just tried to follow this instruction: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library
here is my error message:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-35
    is also present at [mil.nga.geopackage:geopackage-android:2.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-36 value=(false).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-20:19 to override.
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.navi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java, the first `@Override` is also red underlined...

````
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MapView map = null;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //handle permissions first, before map is created. not depicted here

        //load/initialize the osmdroid configuration, this can be done
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        //setting this before the layout is inflated is a good idea
        //it 'should' ensure that the map has a writable location for the map cache, even without permissions
        //if no tiles are displayed, you can try overriding the cache path using Configuration.getInstance().setCachePath
        //see also StorageUtils
        //note, the load method also sets the HTTP User Agent to your application's package name, abusing osm's tile servers will get you banned based on this string

        //inflate and create the map
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //this will refresh the osmdroid configuration on resuming.
        //if you make changes to the configuration, use
        //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //Configuration.getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        map.onResume(); //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //this will refresh the osmdroid configuration on resuming.
        //if you make changes to the configuration, use
        //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //Configuration.getInstance().save(this, prefs);
        map.onPause();  //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }
}```
````

Comment: hey, use the Mapbox. Mapbox uses the osm map and it is so better for you, I think so. check this out -> https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to application element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Modify application tag in your manifest an add this property:

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```